# Webpack v5 builds with a module parsing error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader, webpack-5, babel-loader

I'm currently migrating my project from Webpack v4 to v5 and my build finishes with an Error

```
@My-MacBook-Pro seacat-webui % node --trace-deprecation node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js                                      
assets by status 354 bytes [cached] 1 asset
./src/index.js 2.67 KiB [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 103:1
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (103:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render((
>   <HashRouter>
|       <Application
|           sidebarItemsOrder={sidebarItemsOrder}

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 252 ms
```

The Error has nothing to do with `<HashRouter>` itself, the same message appeares pointing the error to `<Application ... >` if I comment out the hashrouter.

my rules in common.js are

```
exports.getRules = function(config) {
    return [
        {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { presets: [[
                    '@babel/preset-env', 
                    {
                        useBuiltIns: "entry",
                        targets: {
                        esmodules: true,
                        },
                        corejs: {
                            version: "3",
                            proposals: true
                        }
                    }
                ],['@babel/react']], plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"] }
            }],
            exclude: '/node_modules/' 
        },
        {
            test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, //extracts CSS into files
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',  // Second, turn css into commonjs
                    options: { sourceMap: true }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: { sourceMap: true }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader', // First, turn sass into css
                    options: { sourceMap: true }
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*)?$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'assets/svg/[name][contenthash:8][ext]'
            }
        },
    ]
```

webpack.build.js is

```
// imports
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('interpolate-html-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const common = require("./common");

// initial extended configuration
let extendedConfig = {
    extraEntries: {},
    extraOutputs: {},
    extraPlugins: [],
    extraOptimization: {},
    extraModule: {
        extraRules: []
    }
};

const listOfRenamedProps = ["extraEntries", "extraOutputs", "extraPlugins", "extraOptimization", "extraModule"];

// load extended configuration
try {
    extendedConfig = { ...extendedConfig, ...require("../../asab-webui.config") };
    console.log("Extended webpack configuration has been loaded.");
} catch {
    console.log("Extended webpack configuration hasn't been found.");
}

module.exports = {
    build: function(config) {
        // version and build date of the app
        const version = common.getVersion();
        const repository = common.getRepository();
        const buildDate = new Date();
        // paths
        const entry_path = path.resolve(config["dirs"]["src"], 'index.js');
        const html_template_path = path.resolve(config["dirs"]["public"], 'index.html');
        // TODO: This is temporary solution. It will be replaced by date-fns.
        let defaultLocales = /cs/; // Default moment locales (needed for backward compatibility)

        const globalVars = new webpack.DefinePlugin(
            common.JSONStringifyValues({
                "__CONFIG__": config["app"],
                "__DEV_CONFIG__": {},
                "__VERSION__": version,
                "__BUILD_DATE__": buildDate,
                "__REPOSITORY__": repository
            })
        );

        const defaultPlugins = [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: html_template_path,
                minify: {
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeComments: true
                }
            }),
            new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(
                common.convertKeysForHtml(config["app"])
                // Converts keys like this:
                // "publicUrl" -> "__PUBLIC_URL__"
                // "apiUrl" -> "__API_URL__"
            ),
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: false
                    }
                }
            }),
            // Extracts file styles.css
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].css'}),
            // new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'assets/css/[name].css' }),
            // new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
            // Remove moment locales from bundle except those which are defined as second parameter
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, defaultLocales),
        ];

        const filteredExtendedConfig = {...extendedConfig};
        listOfRenamedProps.forEach(prop => delete filteredExtendedConfig[prop]);

        const newModule =  {...extendedConfig.extraModule};
        delete newModule.extraRules;

        return {
            entry: {
                app: entry_path,
                ...extendedConfig.extraEntries
            },
            mode: 'production',
            output: {
                filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:8].bundle.js',
                chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js',
                path: path.resolve(config["dirs"]["dist"]),
                publicPath: '',
                // assetModuleFilename: "images/[hash][ext][query]",
                ...extendedConfig.extraOutputs
            },
            resolve: config["webpack"]["resolve"],
            module: {
                rules: [
                    ...common.getRules(config),
                    ...extendedConfig.extraModule.extraRules
                ],
                ...newModule
            },
            plugins: [
                globalVars,
                ...defaultPlugins,
                ...extendedConfig.extraPlugins
            ],
            optimization: {
                splitChunks: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    cacheGroups: {
                        vendor: {
                            name: 'vendors',
                            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((?!(date-fns)).*)[\\/]/,
                            chunks: 'all',
                            enforce: true
                        },
                        commons: {
                            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                            name(module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
                              const moduleFileName = module
                                .identifier()
                                .split('/')
                                .reduceRight((item) => item);
                              const allChunksNames = chunks.map((item) => item.name).join('~');
                              return `${cacheGroupKey}-${allChunksNames}-${moduleFileName}`;
                            },
                            chunks: 'all',
                        },
                    }
                },
                minimize: true,
                minimizer: [ // Minimizes output javascript
                    `...`,
                    new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
                ],
                ...extendedConfig.extraOptimization
            },
            ...filteredExtendedConfig
        };
    }
}
```

and src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Application } from 'asab-webui';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// Configuration
let ConfigDefaults = {
    ...
};

var modules = [ ... ];

const sidebarItemsOrder = [ ... ];

ReactDOM.render((
    <HashRouter>
        <Application
            sidebarItemsOrder={sidebarItemsOrder}
            configdefaults={ConfigDefaults}
            modules={modules}
            defaultpath={__CONFIG__.defaultpath ? __CONFIG__.defaultpath : "/home"}
            hasSidebar={true}
        />
    </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "seacat-admin-webui",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./asab-webui/script/start.js",
        "build": "node ./asab-webui/script/build.js"
    },
    "author": "TeskaLabs Ltd.",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "description": "Web UI for a SeaCat administration",
    "browserslist": [
        "defaults"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "argparse": "^2.0.1",
        "assign-deep": "^1.0.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
        "babel-polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
        "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
        "cssnano": "^5.1.14",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "interpolate-html-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.19",
        "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
        "window": "^4.2.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@coreui/icons": "^1.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4",
        "core-js": "3",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.2",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "i18next": "^20.1.0",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.0",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.1",
        "react": "^17.0.0",
        "react-content-loader": "^6.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-hook-form": "7.37.0",
        "react-i18next": "^11.8.12",
        "react-json-view": "^1.21.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-simple-tree-menu": "^1.1.18",
        "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.1"
    }
}
```

from my understanding the error happens for a '.js' file and suggests a loader for such file has not been configured, but there is the 'bable-loader' configured for a .js files which worked fine with webpack v4. The generated .js files are working correctly and are split into chunks. Also, the built application works perfectly fine. I want to get rid of all errors to avoid any further issues in the future.

Comment: Have you tried using `@babel/preset-react`?

Comment: yes, the same error appears when I replace ['@babel/react'] with ['@babel/preset-react'] within presets option. (running them simultaneously gives me ``` Error: Duplicate plugin/preset detected. ``` )